# Extract Random Element from Associate Array in JSON Dictionary Using PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, associative-array

I have some JSON that looks like this:

$str = '{"movies":[{"id":"11007","title":"The Pink Panther"},{"id":"11118","Breathless"]}';

This would appear to be a dictionary `{}` with key `"movies"` and value an array `[]` of items that are movies.

After decoding it into an associative array with:

$array = json_decode($str, true);

It looks like:

Array ( [movies] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 11007 [title] => The Pink Panther) [1] => Array ( [id] => 11118 [title] => Breathless) ) )

How can I get a random movie eg The Pink Panther and access its title and id?

array['movies'] just seems to give me the array itself and array_rand($array) also just gives me back the index of the same array since there is only one.

How do I get into the array of movies so that I can grab a random one?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab a random index of the array you want, and then assign. (Json correction here)

```
<?php

$json =
'{
    "movies":
        [
            {"id":"11007","title":"The Pink Panther"},
            {"id":"11118","title":"Breathless"}
        ]
}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$rand_idx = array_rand($data['movies']);
$random_movie = $data['movies'][$rand_idx];

var_export($random_movie);
```

Example output:

```
array (
  'id' => '11118',
  'title' => 'Breathless',
)
```

Comment: Thank-you. You saved the day.